# Can't get kafka console producer or consumer to work

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I was able to get kafka to work fine when I spun it up on my local machine. But when I try to get it to work on an AWS instance nothing seems to work right. I tried spinning up my own server and doing just like I did locally spinning up zookeeper and kafka like so

```
curl http://apache.spinellicreations.com/kafka/0.10.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.tgz | tar -xzf

cd kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0 

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
```

I also tried using the AMI from bitami which seems to be an all in one AMI. Creating the topic seems to work fine. But when I try to run the console producer I get an error

```
SEASPAULSON-MAC:kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0 spaulson$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ec2-54-186-31-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic test
blah
[2016-10-20 12:13:23,395] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test-0
```

I also get an error when I try to start up a console consumer that repeats over and over.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper ec2-54-186-31-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181 --topic test --from-beginning


[2016-10-19 18:26:47,175] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 152 for topics [Set(test)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,ip-172-31-52-58.ec2.internal,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
```

I feel like these kinds of operations should be trivial but it's proving very challenging. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to diagnose issues and figure out what's going wrong. The best I found is this command

```
KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic test --zookeeper ec2-54-186-31-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
Topic:test      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: test     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

Does the Leader: 0 indicate something went wrong? But what?

Comment: For AWS or other IaaS machines, try to set advertised.listeners for your clients

Comment: I need to set advertised listeners on the client? As in the machine I'm trying to connect from? I thought that specifying it as an argument to the shell script would be sufficient.

Comment: It's a broker config that should be set in "server.properties". Then restart the brokers.

Comment: That worked but you should have put it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AWS or any other IaaS machines, you should set "advertised.listeners" for the clients. Here is what this options means in the Kafka doc:

> Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use, if different than the listeners above. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for `listeners` will be used.